# How to configure openvpn server and client to act as fixed ip

Tags: openvpn

We have a linode server in UK with the one click onevpn server installed. this server has a fixed IP.

We want our clients to connect to this such that they appear to have the ip of the server.

In the openvpn web control panel, we assume that you setup a user for each connecting client.

[image: openvpn user permissions]

Does anyone know how we:

1. configure openvpn to allow clients to connect and use its IP.
2. get the required config file for tunnelblick or similar?

Comment: i still not got the point out of your question. if you want to route all traffic through the server then openvpn must be the gateway

Comment: Hi, the above screen shot is the default you get after installing openvpn server. The crux is what should the settings be to act as a fixed IP for anyone connecting?